Performance in OpenLayers 9: Add/Remove Layer or setVisible=True/False?
Let's say you have multiple checkboxes where a user can toggle on and off multiple different layers on the map.
Would you instantiate your map with just those that you know you want to be visible, or would you instantiate your map with all layers, but setting those you don't want to be immediately visible to visible: false.
Are there any performance implications from calling addLayer() and removeLayer() functions repeatedly as a user toggles on and off their desired layers? Or the opposite; are there performance implications by loading everything in and then using setVisible() repeatedly as a user toggles on and off their desired layers instead of add/removeLayer()?
Map Scenario where you only add layers to the map that will be immediately visible:
const osm = new TileLayer({
    source: new OSM(),
    properties: { name: 'osm' },
})

const mvt1 = new VectorTileLayer ({
    source: new VectorTileSource({
        url: url, 
        format: new MVT()
    }),
    style: myStyle,
    properties: { name: 'mvt1'}
})

const mvt2 = new VectorTileLayer ({
    source: new VectorTileSource({
        url: url, 
        format: new MVT()
    }),
    style: myStyle,
    properties: { name: 'mvt2'}
})

const mvt3 = new VectorTileLayer ({
    source: new VectorTileSource({
        url: url, 
        format: new MVT()
    }),
    style: myStyle,
    properties: { name: 'mvt3'}
})

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map'
  view: new View({center[0,0], zoom: 5}),
  layers: [osm, mvt1] //note we only load two layers 
})

Map scenario where you add all layers to the map but use visible property to control immediate visibility:
const osm = new TileLayer({
    visible: true,
    source: new OSM(),
    properties: { name: 'osm' },
})

const mvt1 = new VectorTileLayer ({
    visible: true,
    source: new VectorTileSource({
        url: url, 
        format: new MVT()
    }),
    style: myStyle,
    properties: { name: 'mvt1'}
})

const mvt2 = new VectorTileLayer ({
    visible: false,
    source: new VectorTileSource({
        url: url, 
        format: new MVT()
    }),
    style: myStyle,
    properties: { name: 'mvt2'}
})

const mvt3 = new VectorTileLayer ({
    visible: false,
    source: new VectorTileSource({
        url: url, 
        format: new MVT()
    }),
    style: myStyle,
    properties: { name: 'mvt3'}
})

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map'
  view: new View({center[0,0], zoom: 5}),
  layers: [osm, mvt1, mvt2, mvt3] //note we load all layers
})

